# What does the systemd-resolved service do and does it need to listen on all interfaces?

Tags: linux, systemd

I am working on a project that involves an IOT device (the now deprecated Intel Galileo). I am looking at hardening these devices and I noticed that the `systemd-resolved` service is listening on all interfaces (`0.0.0.0`).

```
root@hostname:~# netstat -altnp
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      240/systemd-resolve
```

After reading the freedesktop.org description of the service [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html),
it states that,

> systemd-resolved is a system service that provides network name resolution to local applications.

I ran a test where I ran `ping` to `google.com` where the `systemd-resolved` was running. I then disabled the service and sent a `ping` to 
`yahoo.com`. There was no packet loss for either request.

**My question(s) are as follows:**

1. What is this service doing?
2. If it is providing name resolution to local applications, why does it listen on the `0.0.0.0` interface?
3. Is this a security concern?
4. What are the potential impacts of disabling this service?

Thanks in advance for any information / help.
Apologies if I have not complied with question format, first time post.
Please edit as required.

Comment: There is currently a security issue with systemd-resolver and so I would keep up to date with patches for this service and in the mean time disable it is possible. Best option would be to create a test rig and test that everything works as expected. Systemd-resolver is designed for systemd inter process communication but many of the legacy applications haven't been written for systemd and so won't reference systemd-resolver.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Raman. We are in the process of testing disabling.
I was aware of an exploit issued on Ubuntu wrt to systemd-resolved. Thanks again

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`systemd-resolved` is needed by systemd. Unless you're installing an alternative DNS resolver, you should keep it.

It's important to note that it is actually listening for UDP packets on `127.0.0.53:53` to do DNS resolution for you:

```
# netstat -npa | grep systemd-resolve
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      205/systemd-resolve
tcp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                    LISTEN      205/systemd-resolve
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           205/systemd-resolve
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*                           205/systemd-resolve
udp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                                205/systemd-resolve
```

The port `5355` sockets are to implement Link-Local Multicast Name Resolution (LLMNR) which is a feature only useful in LANs.

To disable it, edit `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and change the line

```
#LLMNR=yes
```

to

```
LLMNR=no
```

and then restart the service with `service systemd-resolved restart` and check again:

```
# netstat -npa | grep systemd-resolve
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           404/systemd-resolve
```